# How do I match these text lines in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the three first text lines in regex, i.e. the ones ending with form.

```
value="something form"
value="Second cool form"
value="another silly old form"
value="blabla"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What language are you referring to?  Did you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If your question involves regular expressions name the "flavor" (i.e. the program you are using).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what tool you are using, but the following pattern should match the first three lines:

```
.*form"$
```

## Demo

Comment: Imo the only answer that actually solves OP's problem (+1).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use:

```
.*form"$
```

In order to work, you would have to turn on [multiline mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Dot (`.`) means - match me anything but newline character, asterisk (`*`) means - match me dot zero or more times after which comes text `form`. Dollar sign (`$`) is anchor to the string ending.

Take a look at [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSP6kY/4). You should learn more about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), this is basic regex matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
\w*form\b
```

`\w*`: Allows characters in front of `form`

`\b`: Makes sure that `form` is at the end of the string.

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSP6kY/3)

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants the complete value, not only `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to match the 'form' as a separate word, you need something like this:

```
\Wform\W
```

\W (capital W) is any character which does *not* represent a word character, at least in perl-like regex.